# Fuzzy Match in Conditional Karate API Testing Tool

Tags: json, testing, karate, fuzzy

We recently started using Karate as  our integrated testing tool on the project we're currently developing and I've faced an issue recently which I'd like to know why is happening. Let's go through this:

One of the tests we do in all our APIs  is the response time.  When we started creating our tests we've created a series of common features that would be used for many different APIs tests. One of these features is the testGetAll.feature in  which we send as  parameters an endpoint, an optional list of paramenters, an authentication key and an optional response time.

Before we call the service, we have this code:

```
* def rTime = (__arg.rTime == '#notnull' ? __arg.rTime : MEDIUM_RESPONSE_TIME)
```

And then, to test if it was  working, I've written the following:

```
* print "argRtime : " + __arg.rTime
* print __arg.rTime == '#notnull' 
* print "rTime : " + rTime
```

And as result Ive got:
    argRtime = 3000
    false
    rTime = 500

Why is this conditional false if __arg.rTime is not null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose all the karate inbuilt  **fuzzy matching markers** only work with `match`.

```
__arg.rTime == '#notnull'
```

is a simple javascript evaluation, not karate `match`, so here RHS will be considered as a string and evaluated.

However,

```
* match __arg.rTime == '#notnull'
```

will work perfectly.

But for your logic you can try,

```
* def rTime = ( __arg.rTime != null ? __arg.rTime : MEDIUM_RESPONSE_TIME)
```

> Karate fuzzy matching marker should be only used with **match**

Answer (score 2):

You can use fuzzy matchers on this line with `karate.match` from [the `karate` object](https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object) like this:

```
* def rTime = karate.match(__arg.rTime, '#notnull').pass ? __arg.rTime : MEDIUM_RESPONSE_TIME)
```

Comment: Nice! I haven't noticed return type of this API.